How can I continue from here proving there is no limit to the right of $x_0=0$?
When composing  $g$ on $f$ at $x=0$ and checking if there exists a limit to the right of $x$, I get that there is no limit this is because if I wrote the composition correctly as I take numbers larger than zero the function keeps switching  between $0$ and $1$
$$
f=x \cdot D(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
x & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g=\text{sgn}(y) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } y > 0 \\
0 & \text{if } y = 0 \\
-1 & \text{if } y < 0 
\end{cases}
$$
here is the function that I got
$$
(g \circ f)(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } x > 0 \\
-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } x < 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \text{ or } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
the thing is I am not sure how to prove this using epsilon delta I can see it is almost the same as Dirichlet function proof but if some explanation on how to write this can be given  it would be a great learning experience.
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists a limit ($L \in \mathbb{R})$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} h(x) = L.$
Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}.$ According to the epsilon-delta definition, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that:
$
0 < x_1, x_2 < \delta \quad \text{and} \quad x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}, x_2 \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \implies |h(x_1) - h(x_2)| < 2\epsilon
$
For $x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$:
$$h(x_1) = g(f(x_1)) = g(x_1) = 1 \quad \text{(since $ x_1 > 0 $)}
$$
$$
|h(x_1) - 1| = |1 - 1| = 0 < \frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
|h(x_2)-0| = |1 - 1| = 0 < \frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
|h(x_1) - h(x_2)| = |1 - 0| = 1
$$
$$1 = |h(x_1) - h(x_2)| \leq |h(x_1) - L| + |L - h(x_2)|$$
Since $|h(x_1) - L| < \epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ and $|L - h(x_2)| < \epsilon = \frac{1}{4} $:
$$
1 < \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
This contradicts but $1>1/2$ contradiction.

Are you asking to prove $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(f(x))$$ doesn't exist?

yes , is this assumption incorrect ?

No, just making sure. Hint: if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} h(x)$ exists then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(h(1/n)-h(\sqrt 2/n)\right)\to 0.$$

Pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. Show that for any $\delta\gt 0$, you can find real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $|a|,|b|\lt\delta$, but $|f(a)-f(b)|\gt2\epsilon$. This means that there can be no limit, for if there were a limit $L$, then you would be able to find $\delta$ to force $|f(a)-L|\lt\epsilon$ and $|f(b)-L|\lt\epsilon$, and that would imply $|f(a)-f(b)|\lt2\epsilon$.

we are yet  to learn limit as the number approaches infinity so I don't think I have the tools to use this yet

I will try this @ArturoMagidin  now

I will try to write what I tried in the question if you can check it @ArturoMagidin

Your "try" was fine.

Note that if the limit of a function $h(x)$ as $x\to x_0$ is $L$, then for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that: if $a$ and $b$ are such that $0\lt |a-x_0|\lt \delta$ and $0\lt |b-x_0|\lt\delta$, then $|h(a)-h(b)|\lt2\epsilon$.  (I'm assuming $h$ is defined in an open interval that contains $x_0$, except perhaps at $x_0$. Suitable modifications for more general definitions will work.)
Indeed, since the limit exists and is equal to $L$ we know there exists $\delta$ such that if $0\lt |c-x_0|\lt\delta$,, then $|h(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$. Picking that same $\delta$, since$ 0\lt|a-x_0|\lt \delta$ and $0\lt|b-x_0|\lt\delta$, then we have both $|h(a)-L|\lt\epsilon$ and $|h(b)-L|\lt\epsilon$. Then, using the triangle inequality, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
|h(a)-h(b)| &= |h(a)-L +L-h(b)|\\
&\leq |h(a)-L|+|L-h(b)|\\
&= |h(a)-L| + |h(b)-L|\\
&\lt \epsilon + \epsilon\\
&= 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}g\circ f(x)$ does not exist, it suffices to show that there is an $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that for every $\delta\gt 0$ we can find $a$ and $b$ such that:

$0\lt a \lt\delta$ and $0\lt b \lt \delta$; and
$|g(f(a))-g(f(b))|\geq 2\epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. Let $\delta\gt 0$. Then we can find a rational number $a$ with $0\lt a\lt\delta$ and an irrational number $b$ with $0\lt b\lt\delta$. Then $g(f(a)) = 1$ and $g(f(b))=0$, so $|g(f(a))-g(f(b))|=|1-0|=1\geq 2\epsilon$.
Thus, the limit of $g\circ f$ as $x\to 0^+$ cannot exist.

sorry took me a while to read and make sure everything is understandable , thank you again
